# How can I import facebook latest api in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I download latest api and it includes **.aar** file and there is **classes.jar**  but I cant import it. I ve searched it a lot. Please help me how can I import facebook api to my project on eclipse.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you haven't switched to Android Studio and Gradle yet?

Comment: I am not familiar with it :)

Comment: Here you go: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. I'd highly recommend to start using Android Studio since it's the official Android IDE at the moment, and is actively supported.

Comment: so , anyone can help ?